# SQL Server 2008 Array Query

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server-2008

I have a table structure

```
ID         [integer]
Name
RecoveryID [integer]
date
```

I want to search on the `RecoveryID` with an array and reveal all those in the array without a corresponding record.

so, if my table contains

```
1,'John',1,20-10-2013
2,'John',4,20-10-2013
3,'John',5,20-10-2013
```

And I search on the `RecoveryID` with the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` I would want the result `[2,3,6]`

I have tried using various `IN`, `NOT IN` statements, but I always get what I have, not what I don't have.

To try and explain further, I am trying to Outer Join without a second table. I have a list of users, a list of things that CAN be done (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and a list of things that NEED to be done by a specific user.  {[John],(1,2,7)} For example.

If John completes action 1, my work table now contains ('John',1,20-10-2013) actions 2 & 7 are remaining.  I have the list (1,2,7)  how can I query the work table so that it returns (2,7) ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: have you used combination of IN and NOT IN? this is quite simple

Comment: sorry bro, i dont understand your questions, there are 3 data in your table with array structures, and u trying to get result with 2,3,6?

Comment: @Lu Duy Khanh : So simple you could not share the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Except set operation as :

```
SELECT n
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) AS Nums(n)
EXCEPT
SELECT RecoveryID from table1
```

Comment: This did not quite work, but it did send me on the right track:`SELECT items.recovered
FROM 
(    
  VALUES('1'),('2'),('3'),('4')
) AS items(recovered)
EXCEPT
SELECT recovered FROM dbo.TR_CGradeReport;` I don't know why adding apostrohes works, but hey! it works :)

Comment: yeah in case you come across two sets where you need to find results as A-B , you can use Except operator.